# Word for saying something in a superior tone

Tags: word-request

What is the word for "say something in a tone that shows superiority over the other"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you might be looking for the word **Authoritative**, which has the following definition:

> commanding and self-confident; likely to be respected and obeyed.

You could then say that someone speaks with an **Authoritative tone**

I hope this helps :)

Comment: :) I got it. I had the word somewhere in my mind but I could not get it on my tongue. You really helped. Thank you.